# Problem related to the QTableWidget() of the PyQt5 library

Tags: python, authentication, input, limit, digits

I created new QTableWidget() widget and it has some elements and during execution new ones will be created. And i am going to limit users to enter only digits. How can i do it?

If you need full code let me know

i tried to do one-by-one and failed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok.
everything is imported. i will give part related to question:

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Integer'])
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, NumberTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, NumberTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
i am going to limit input to only digits fo rthis table.